# Missing XML Namespaces in XSLT

Tags: xml-parsing, namespaces, xslt-2.0

Am trying to render web service response through XSLT. Created text area to display specific xml elements. I see the xml namespaces in the web service response but when am trying to display them in XSLT text area, it's not displaying XML namespaces.

What could be the issue with XSLT ? Details element has XML content which I need to display as it is. Details1 text area has XML namespaces, however, Details2 text area doesn't. I cross checked the webservice response and it has Xml namespaces for both Details1 & Details2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-16"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="myForm" method="post" action="/MyServlet">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name1</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="name1" rows="2" cols="10"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address1</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="address1" rows="2" cols="10"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Details1</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="details1" rows="10" cols="50"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name2</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="name2" rows="2" cols="10"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address2</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="address2" rows="2" cols="10"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Details2</th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="details2" rows="10" cols="50"
                                > </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:element name="input">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">submit</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">Submit</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:element name="input">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="type">Reset</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="value">Cancel</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Post your code to help us help you.

Comment: Your stylesheet doesn't appear to make any access to any source document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove default namespace and keep the rest of namespaces using XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023533/how-to-remove-default-namespace-and-keep-the-rest-of-namespaces-using-xslt)